# Utilizando ESLint no VS Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

Olá! Sou um estudante novo de JavaScript e estou descobrindo o mundo da padronização de código.

Resumindo, bem minha situação, estou utilizando o combo ESLinter + Prettier no VS Code e minha dúvida é: Toda vez que eu abrir um projeto novo no Node.js preciso instalar os recursos (npx eslinter, npm prettier, etc.) ?

Como posso fazer para salvar minhas definições do ESLinter e Prettier para usar em todos os meus projetos e, quando participar de um projeto em equipe, apenas adicionar o documento com as padronizações da equipe?

Comment: Você precisa instalar como dependência de desenvolvimento para que qualquer pessoa que trabalhe no projeto tenha essas dependências. Além disso, você pode ter configurações próprias com as extensões do VS Code mas o ideal é ter tudo nos arquivos de configuração do ESLint e Prettier porque assim você compartilha com todos da equipe sem conflito de regras, e copia esses arquivos de um projeto pro outro. Se for o caso, pode fazer pacotes de configuração como o [Airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/packages)

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar, precisamos saber qual padrão você vai usar, mas vamos lá.

---

> ### Crie o arquivo .eslintrc globalmente

OS: 
`Linux: root@USERNAME` > code .eslintrc.json 
`Windows:C:\users\USERNAME\document(o?)s ou C:\users\USERNAME` echo "">.eslintrc.json

Com, por exemplo, o seguinte conteúdo bem simples:

```
{
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended"],
  "rules": {
     // enable additional rules
     "indent": ["error", 4],
     "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
     "quotes": ["error", "double"],
     "semi": ["error", "always"],

     // override default options for rules from base configurations
     "comma-dangle": ["error", "always"],
     "no-cond-assign": ["error", "always"],

     // disable rules from base configurations
     "no-console": "off"
  }
}
```

> ### Instale os pacotes globalmente

```
npm install -g eslint-config-prettier eslint-config-standard eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-node eslint-plugin-prettier eslint-plugin-promise eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-standard prettier
```

> ### Instale a extensão do editor, no caso do VS Code, esta:

ESlint 2.1.14 (Integrates ESLint Javascript Into VS Code) Autor: Dirk Baeumer

Reinicie o VS Code.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não se esqueça de dar uma olhada nos links abaixo. São da própria documentação oficial.

REFERÊNCIA: 
https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#extending-configuration-files 
https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--resolve-plugins-relative-to
https://medium.com/wearelaika/javascript-eslint-global-configuration-setup-vscode-599cbfc81eb5
https://medium.com/medvine/install-eslint-global-with-airbnb-style-guide-and-use-it-in-vscode-d752dfa40b21

Answer (score 0):

> Toda vez que eu abrir um projeto novo no Node.js preciso instalar os recursos (npx eslinter, npm prettier, etc.) ?

Sim pois são pacotes externos como outras libs.

> Como posso fazer para salvar minhas definições do ESLinter e Prettier para usar em todos os meus projetos e, quando participar de um projeto em equipe, apenas adicionar o documento com as padronizações da equipe?

1. No caso do ESLinter, você pode criar um arquivo eslintrc e adicionar as regras que são importantes para o seu projeto.
2. No caso do Prettier, você pode o .editorconfig ou .prettierrc.json com os padrões que você deseja no projeto

Links para consulta:

https://blog.cod3r.com.br/configurando-a-extensao-prettier-no-visual-studio-code/
[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://blog.betrybe.com/ferramentas/vs-code-guia-completo/)
https://blog.cod3r.com.br/organizacao-e-padronizacao-com-eslint/
https://medium.com/@guimaraessilas/padroniza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-com-eslint-prettier-e-vscode-e5f7f9cd3bb
https://matheusteixeirajs.medium.com/como-configurar-eslint-e-prettier-para-seus-projetos-em-react-nodejs-e-typescript-53a2c0b9f5d4

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).